# Prove that there exists $e > 0$ and $b \in B$ so that $b - e$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty bounded subsets of $R$ such that $\sup A < \sup B$. Prove that there exists $e > 0$ and $b \in B$ so that $b - e$ if an upper bound of $A$.
I'm having trouble formalizing a proof for this.
Since A and B are bounded, by AoC we can say there is a supremum for both of them. We know $\sup A < \sup B$, which is saying that A has a smaller least upper bound than B. To prove that there is a positive $e$ that we can show $b-e$ is an upper bound of A for is what I am struggling to understand and how to prove.

Comment: That doesn't help me to prove it though, im still stuck

Answer (score 2):

$\sup A$ is not an upper bound for $B$,

there is a

$ b \in B$ with

$a \le \sup A < b \le \sup B$;

$d:= b -\sup A >0$.

Choose $\epsilon =d/2$, then

$a \le \sup A =b -d < b -d/2 =$

$b - \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sup B\gt \sup A$, there exists  $\varepsilon\gt 0$ such that  $\sup B\gt \sup A+\varepsilon$ (Take  $\varepsilon=\frac{\sup B - \sup A}2$).

So  $\varepsilon' :=\sup B - \sup A-\varepsilon\gt 0$. Then there exists  $b\in B $ such that $\sup B-\varepsilon' \leq b$. Simplifying we get $\sup A\leq b -\varepsilon.$